# Exracting fields in file and storing it in different file in vim

Tags: command-line, vim

I have file int the following format:

```
.

.

.

Name:abc

Occupation:def

.

.

Name:xyz

Occupation:ghi

.

.
```

I want to extract the name and occupation field and save it in another file out.txt using `vim` in the following format:

```
Name:abc

Occupation:def

Name:def

Occupation:ghi
```

EDIT:Occupation field position in input file updated

Comment: In your example of the input file, you didn't show us how the "occupation" information is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggyG:e out.txt<cr>p:v/Name\|Occupation/d<cr>:w<cr>
```

Explanation

```
gg # Go to beginning of file
y  # yank (copy)
G  # to end of file
:e out.txt # Open a new file called out.txt
p  # paste what you just copied
:v/Name\|Occupation/d # Delete all lines that don't contain Name or Occupation
:w # save
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you write your `vim` buffer and quit (`:wq`) and use this instead:

```
grep -E '^(Name|Occupation)' your_file >out.txt
```

The `grep` command will print out any lines in `your_file` matching the pattern we give it. The pattern used here requires extended regular expressions, which is why I'm using the `-E` switch to `grep`. The pattern is as follows:

- `^` means start of line
- `(Name|Occupation)` means to search for either `Name` or `Occupation`
- Taken together, the regular expression means look for lines starting with the word `Name` or lines starting with the word `Occupation`.

Left alone, the `grep` command would have printed all matching lines to the terminal. The last bit (`>out.txt`) [redirects](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) the output of the `grep` command to the file `out.txt` instead of the terminal.

Comment: You can avoid saving the buffer by going to line 1 (`1G`) and issuing `:.,$!grep -E '^(Name|Occupation)'`

Comment: You can indeed; I was actually implying that `vim` need not be used for this.

Comment: Yes, though it is possible in vim as Kevin has proven above :D

Answer (score 1):

VIM :

```
:g/\./d | sav /tmp/otherFileName
```

SED :

```
sed '/\(\.\)/d' InputFile >> /tmp/otherFileName
```

Most Perfect :

```
:v/^Name*\|^Occupation*/d | s/^Name/\r&/g | sav /tmp/OtherFileName
```

Comment: Why do we need a s(find and replace)

Comment: it's just for appending new line for proper look..

Comment: But it is not working without s(I mean even output without new line)

Answer (score 0):

Outside of `vim`, which *could* be used to achieve the result, there a host of command line tools that could achieve the same result. Using perl as an example:

```
 perl -n -e '$name=$1 if(/^(Name: .+)$/); print "$name\n\n$_\n" if(/^Occupation: .+/);' < file > out.txt
```

`perl -n` tells perl to wrap each line of the standard input (`STDIN`) in a while loop.
We can redirect a file to the `STDIN` if we use `< file` at the end of the perl command.

This has the effect of allowing you to run perl commands on each line of the `file` we redirected.

We then specify what commands perl should run with the `-e` option, which we follow by:

```
'$name=$1 if(/^(Name: .+)$/); print "$name\n\n$_\n" if(/^Occupation: .+/);'
```

(note the single quotes `'` around the perl instructions, as perl needs the -e option as a single argument on the command line).

As to the logic of the code,

```
 $name=$1 if(/^(Name: .+)$/);
```

if a line starts `^` with `Name:` followed by one or more characters `.+` and then the end of the line `$`, we can store all of this match if we wrap it in `()` and it will become available in a special variable called `$1`. So all of `Name: whatever` is stored in  `$1`. We then assign this to a variable called `$name`.

Similar to the previous instruction, we next do:

```
 print "$name\n\n$_\n" if(/^Occupation: .+/);'
```

if a line starts `^` with `Occupation:` followed by one or more characters `.+` and then the end of line `$`, then print the previously matched name line (stored in $name), two newlines `\n\n` and then `$_` which is the contents of the present line the while loop is processing (in our case the match Occupation line), followed by another newline `\n`;

Finally we redirect output from this command to out.txt with `> out.txt`.

There is an assumption that every `Name:` is followed (some lines after it) with an Occupation related to that `Name:`, if you have multiple Occupation lines, then you will print more than one name and occupation. Also if the name has no Occupation line, it will not get printed out.